# MongoTemplate - where with JS function

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

I need to query the db with the $where operator from Java Spring mongoTemplate.
This is the query:

```
db.myCollection.find( {$where : function () {
    for (var index in this.*someKey*){
        if (index.indexOf(*someValue*) > -1){
          return this;
        }
    }
}})
```

But the mongoTemplate where operator expects to receive key not java script string function. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: I guess you can use Javascript Expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Spring MongoDB repositories(I needed paging as well)

```
public interface MyCollectionRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyCollectionClass, String> {
    @Query("{$where : ?0}")
    Page<MyCollectionClass> findSomething(String whereQuery, Pageable pageable);

     .....
}
```

And

```
 public static String whereQuery(String someValue){
        return "function() {" +
                    "for (var index in this.*someKey*){" +
                        "if (index.indexOf(\""+ someValue+"\") > -1){" +
                          "return this;" +
                         "}" +
                     "}" +
                "}";
    }
```